# How to slow down the speed of UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, methods, performance, uigesturerecognizer

I have a method that I would like to call when a 2 finger pan gesture is recognized. I have it setup and working ok, but the problem is that there is only about 15 times I need the method to be called (it filters through images), and by the time I've panned about an inch, the method has been called a hundred times and the images went by so fast I didn't know what was going on.

What can I do to slow down my gesture recognizer?

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self view] addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're changing images every time you get a pan event. That's not very good. Instead you should ask the pan gesture recognizer for the drag distance (use `-translationInView:`) and only change images once you've passed a specific threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I created a "responseCount" basically capturing every 4th or 5th (valid) gesture.

```
// within method that fires with each gesture:
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panRecognizer translationInView:aView];
if(abs(translatedPoint.x) > 20 || abs(translatedPoint.y) > 20){
    if(responseCount == 4){
        // do animation/response
        responseCount = 0;
    } else {
        responseCount += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4**

```
@objc func panGestureHandler(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let theViewMinimumY = someValue
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view)

    switch gesture.state {

    case .began:
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gesture.view)

    case .changed:

        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gesture.view)

        // if the view ever goes beyond a certain point
        if theView.frame.origin.y < theViewMinimumY {

            // only add a fraction of the gesture's translation (in this case 50%)
            theView.center = CGPoint(x: theView.center.x, y: theView.center.y + (translation.y * 0.5))

        } else {

            theView.center = CGPoint(x: theView.center.x, y: theView.center.y + translation.y)

        }

    case .ended:

        ...

    default:
        break

    }

}
```